# How do quantum field values combine?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, superposition, foundations

I am interested in how quantum field values combine under superpositions of states in the case of free real scalar fields.

I believe I understand the following:

- A fock basis of a free real scalar particle Hilbert space can be expressed in terms of application of creation operators of specific positions or momenta on the ground state.
- A general state of the Hilbert space can be expressed from superposition of fock states.
- There is a "local Hilbert space state" (I don't know the proper name), associated with each position or each momentum. This is a state in a system with similar mathematics to a quantum harmonic oscillator, with the dynamical value being the field value at that point. For momenta the systems are independent so they also have the same dynamics as an oscillator.

Considering the field at one moment of time, my question concerns an object  $s(v, x, y, z) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $v, x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ which represents the amplitude of each value ($v$) of each oscillator system (at $x$, $y$, $z$). This can clearly I think represent all fock states by just having the appropriate oscillator state at each $x$, $y$, $z$. (I would love to know the name for this object if it is correct and has a standard name).

I would like to know:

- Can all states of the particle field (not just Fock states) be represented by $s$ under the same interpretation?
- If yes, how does $s$ combine under superposition of states? Does addition of states simply correspond to function addition of $s$ functions (and normalisation) (ie. is $s$ just a direct representation of the field Hilbert space)?

Comment: Just think about it like ordinary QM. A single harmonic oscillator could be in a position eigenstate, like $|x \rangle$. A superposiiton of $|x \rangle$ and $|y \rangle$ is not described by $|x + y \rangle$, it's described by $|x \rangle + |y \rangle$. The same goes for quantum fields -- the wavefunctional can be written a superposition of field eigenstates.

Comment: @knzhou Thank you for commenting. In the case for a single harmonic oscillator, my s would be s(v)→ℂ (regular wavefunction). With this my understanding is that |0> superposed with |1> would be 1/√2 |0> + 1/√2 |1>. The equivalent for s functions (now just wavefunctions) is s0 (first Hermine function, looks like bell function) superposed with s1 (second Hermite function), which is simple function addition: 1/√2 s0 + 1/√2 s1. Of course there can be a relative phase constant also. I am not sure if you are saying it is similar to this for fields, or this is not the right intuition.